# Set Woocommerce new orders to "On hold" without going to "Processing"

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, checkout, orders

Is it possible to set all new orders to on hold without them going to processing first?

I need to capture the funds, but the order needs to go as on-hold rather than processing so that I can make sure the payment is received before triggering the email to our supplier.

I have found some code that allows me to change all new orders to on-hold, however when payment is authorized the order is set to processing.

**pending payment --> processing (triggers email) --> on-hold**

[Screenshot of Order Notes that show this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CU1LX.png)

This is the code that I found:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_thankyou', 'custom_woocommerce_auto_onhold_order' );

function custom_woocommerce_auto_onhold_order( $order_id ) {
global $woocommerce;
if ( !$order_id )
return;
$order = new WC_Order( $order_id );
$order->update_status( 'on-hold' ); //All new orders go to "on-hold"
}
```

I've been looking for the action which triggers the order status to be set to processing on payment authorization however I cannot find it.

All help is greatly appreciated!

Edit: I've managed to stumble upon a snippet of code that appears to work.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_payment_complete_order_status', 'custom_update_order_status', 10, 2 );

function custom_update_order_status( $order_status, $order_id ) {

return 'on-hold'; 

}
```

Comment: Your edited additional code **will never allow you to change an order to completed status**… Also it's trigger after order creation on status_update action…

Answer (score 0):

> All orders start with a "pending" status in Woocommerce. That status is set before they go through the payment gateway...
>
> There is no email notifications for "Pending" orders staus

You can try the following, that will **set the status** "on-hold" **on order creation** *(The update status action comes once the order has been created ans saved in database)*:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_create_order', 'force_new_order_status', 20, 1 );
function force_new_order_status( $order ) {

    if( ! $order->has_status('on-hold') )
        $order->set_status( 'on-hold', 'Forced status by a custom script' );
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the help, I'll try it out!

Comment: @GRitchie All orders start with pending status in woocommerce. That status is set before they go through the payment gateway... My code works on Order creation, before data is saved to database and I don't update order status but I set it before order is saved